# Parameter based sort in Birt Crosstab

Tags: sorting, parameters, birt, crosstab

I want to allow the crosstab report I am making to be sorted based on what column is selected within a parameter but I can't quite get it to work. I am currently using version 2.5.2.

When I set the column to be sorted by something like data["Emp_Num"] it works.

However, if I try to have it sort by params["Sort"].value and then set the parameter to data["Emp_Num"] it does not seem to pick it up. I don't think I need to write a script for this, but am I wrong in thinking that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: My first thought would be to use a computed column, and sort on that.  Any reason you can't do this?

Comment: ...or to define a column in the query that is based on the parameter?